# Choosing best suitable data type from the list of data types

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

Given the list of data types like `['long', 'int', 'short']`, how to select the best suitable data type that can handle any value of any of the given types?

In this case, best data type is `long`. So return `long`. I am already of a way(brute force) but I am looking for right way to tackle it. Suggest me the best suitable design.

Below is my current solution:

```
static Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
  map.add("long", Lists.newArrayList("long", "int", "short", "byte"));
  map.add("int", Lists.newArrayList("int", "short", "byte"));
  .
  .
}

public void String suitableDataType(List<String> input) {
  if (input.contains("long") && input.stream().allMatch(t -> map.get("long").contains(t)))
    return "long";
  else if(..int..)
    return "int";
  .
  .
  .
  else
    return "string";

}
```

Basically construct a map of data type to all possible data types it can support.
And check manually in the order of `long, int, short` within `input` and also check if all the data types within `input` are supported using map and return the respective type.

But I am not satisfied with this approach. So looking for best way to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to clarify why you are not satisfied with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that an enum could be useful, but you can use a different approach like a map. The point is to have a numeric value associated with each type.

I think I renamed the method and changed the return type ... please consider only the concept

```java
   private enum TYPE {
        LONG, INT, SHORT, BYTE;
    }

   private static void examine(List<String> input){
    TYPE type = TYPE.LONG;
        for (String key : input) {
            switch(key){
                case "byte":
                    System.out.print("byte"); 
                    return;
                default: 
                    type = type.ordinal() < TYPE.valueOf(key.toUpperCase()).ordinal() ? TYPE.valueOf(key.toUpperCase()) : type;
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(type);
    }
```

You have considered the "string" as the default; in my example I used "byte" instead, but, also in this case, it's the logic the main thing. Once you established the hierarchy of the data types all will come as consequence.

In the worst case, all the stuff is done in O(n).